# Socket closes after sending a message, thus making receiving message impossible

Tags: java, android, websocket, android-asynctask

I have a server handler class in my android app that reads and write messages in the Socket, the socket gets passed to it by the `ClientController` which runs this socket in `AsyncTask`. connection to the server establishes and I can send a message to it, but once I get the response back the serverhandler cannot read it and logs the `Error: Socket closed`. I'm not very sure where the problem is, it might be threading issue with android.
here is how my ServerHandler class look like:

```
public class ServerHandler extends Handler implements Runnable {
    private static  ServerHandler instance ;
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServerHandler.class);
//    private static final Object lock = new Object();  // For thread-safety
    private final Socket serverSocket;
    private final PrintWriter broadcaster;
    private final ClientController clientController = ClientController.getInstance();


    @Getter
    public enum State {
//some States i need for message handling
    }
    @Getter
    private State expectedState = State.CONNECT_MENU;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new NewLineAppendingSerializer<>())
            .create();

    public static synchronized ServerHandler getInstance(Socket socket) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ServerHandler(socket);
        }
        return instance;}
    public ServerHandler(Socket socket) {

        this.serverSocket = socket;
        PrintWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            writer = null;
        }
        broadcaster = writer;
}



    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(() ->{
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(serverSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                        serverSocket.getOutputStream(), false);

                String request, response;
                while (true) {

                    if ((request = reader.readLine()) != null
                            && (response = handle(request)) != null) {
                        logger.info("this is the message from server: " + request);
                        writer.println(response);
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException | MalformedJsonException e) {
                // Handle MalformedJsonException
                logger.error("The request is not in json format: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error while trying to read the server message: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error while trying to close the connection: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
                ).start();
    }
    /**
     * Writes the specified message to the broadcaster
     */
    public void broadcast(String message) {
        new Thread(() -> {try (PrintWriter writer = this.broadcaster) {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.write(message);
                writer.flush();
            } else {
                logger.error("Error broadcasting message: broadcaster is null");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error broadcasting message", e);
        }}).start();


    }


    private String handle(String request) {
// handles the messages
}
```

and here is how the Socket is initiated and passed to ServerHandler:

```
public class ClientController {

    // some variables
    private ClientController() {
        new SocketInitializationTask().execute();

    }

    private static class SocketInitializationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Socket> {
        @Override
        protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String serverAddress = "192.168.0.208";
                int serverPort = 8082;
                return new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Failed connection");
                // Handle exception
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket) {
            if (socket != null) {

                // Set the serverHandler in the ClientController
                instance.serverHandler = new ServerHandler(socket);
                instance.serverHandler.run();

                


            }
        }
    }
```

and from this class i can send messages using the Broadcast method in serverhandler.

first I ran everything on the main thread but ofc Android didn't allow it so I got suggested to use `AsyncTask` for socket initialization.
Now I do have connection to the server and I can send messages to it, but after sending the first message the socket closes, making the serverhandler not able to read messages.
And from the server side I tested if it was the server that closes the socket but it wasn't.

I need the socket to stay open all the time, so I can read messages from the Server.

Comment: If  `readLine()` returns null you must exit the  read loop. I don’t see any closes here. You haven’t shown the accept loop.